# groupby count based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, grouping

I've a problem and i don't know where to start, currently i am working on running interval training data, like the data example below. i've got timestamps, power and heart rate data.
the ultimate goal is to calculate how long it takes to reach maximum heart rate. however I can only start counting when an interval starts, this is the case when power values are > 200, from that timestamp I want to count to the moment maximum heart rate is reached. The difficulty is that there are multiple interval blocks in a session and the whole dataset contains multiple dates as well.

the final goal is to have a 2 columns, first column tells the number of the interval and the second column will tell how many seconds it took to reach maximum heart rate

currently i have no clue where to start

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data= pd.DataFrame(
    [[pd.Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:04'), 140, 120],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:11:05'), 400, 155],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:13:06'), 400, 160],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:15:07'), 100, 155],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:15:08'), 430, 160],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-05 10:17:09'), 430, 130],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-07 10:17:10'), 430, 131],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-07 10:17:11'), 430, 170],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-07 10:18:06'), 430, 156],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-07 10:19:07'), 130, 155],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-07 10:19:08'), 130, 160],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-07 10:19:09'), 430, 130],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-07 10:20:10'), 430, 131],
    [pd.Timestamp('2022-08-07 10:20:11'), 130, 170]],
    columns=['timestamp', 'power', 'heart rate'])

result = pd.DataFrame([[1, 30], [2, 35], [3,40]], columns=['n_interval', 'time_to_reach_max_hr'])
```

Comment: Can you add expected result

Comment: yes, i've implemented  this

Comment: @pepijn 'result' is the expected result, based on the given data? It's not clear to me how to count: 1 rows the countdown starts power> 200, where does the countdown end, on which line (interval)?